# Distance between textview in listview android

Tags: android, listview

I have a ListView and TextView in it.
Also have a selector image.
How could i make the distance between textviews bigger

TEXTVIEW

```
    <TextView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:textSize="@dimen/menu_item_size"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:shadowRadius="5"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_color"
        android:shadowColor="@color/menu_glow"
        android:shadowDy="3"
        android:shadowDx="3" />

    LISTVIEW
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/menu1">
            <ListView
               android:id="@+id/ListView_Menu"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="244dp"
               android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
               android:padding="2dp"
               android:divider="@drawable/divider">
            </ListView>
```

Comment: Can you show in image what exactly you want to do.

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="20dip" for your listView. 20dip - is arbitrary value - play with it to get results you want